# Undefined or null reference on autocomplete query

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'results' of undefined or null reference returned

when I'm loading a page due to the following code:

```js
  $( function() {
   var systemNameList = [ ];
   $.ajax({
    url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Application List')/items?$select=Title&$top=1000",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"accept" : "application.json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function (data) {
     systemNameList = data.d.results;
     console.log(systemNameList);
    }
   });
    $( "#systemName" ).autocomplete({
      source: systemNameList
    });
  } );
```

It's intended to retrieve a list of systems from a list that can be added to and create an array for them to then be searchable with the autocomplete to give suggestions when typing into an input box, however it seems to error around the ajax query results, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you do `console.log(data.d)` what do you see?

Comment: Are you sure that data.d has value?

Comment: Your autocomplete call needs to be in the success callback

Comment: I'm getting ````undefined```` returned with a console.log(data.d), however I've tested the ajax url and it returns results normally.

Comment: `console.log(data, typeof data)`